# Get host name from tcp/udp packets with sockets / Linux and "raw" python

Tags: python, networking, tcp, packet, packet-sniffers

following a tutorial I coded a wifi sniffer in python using sockets (on linux) and the "struct" package. The code is splitted in two parts: the first one decodes the Ipv4 header packets getting the Ips and other information and then sends the remaining data to the second part which decodes ICMP, UDP and TCP packets. When I decode the TCP and UDP packets I can easily get source ports and destinations ports, flags etc... but I'm now looking for the host name. In other words Im trying to see which website is visited by the packet sender/receiver.

How can I get the host name? Is it in the "data" part of the tcp/udp packet, if so how to decode it? Do I have to look at the source and destination ports?

Here is the code: 2 functions for UDP/TCP packets, the data argument is the "data" part from a Ipv4 packet.

```
def tcp_segment(data):
    (src_port, dest_port, sequence, acknowledgement, offset_reserved_flags) = struct.unpack('! H H L L H', data[:14])
    offset = (offset_reserved_flags >> 12) * 4
    flag_urg = (offset_reserved_flags & 32) >> 5
    flag_ack = (offset_reserved_flags & 16) >> 4
    flag_psh = (offset_reserved_flags & 8) >> 3
    flag_rst = (offset_reserved_flags & 4) >> 2
    flag_syn = (offset_reserved_flags & 2) >> 1
    flag_fin = offset_reserved_flags & 1

    return src_port, dest_port, sequence, acknowledgement, flag_urg, flag_ack, flag_psh, flag_rst, flag_syn, flag_fin, data[offset:]

def udp_segment(data):
    src_port, dest_port, size = struct.unpack('! H H 2x H', data[:8])
    return src_port, dest_port, size, data[8:]
```

[TCP packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6FL5.jpg)

Comment: The host name would only be in an HTTP header. Other protocols do not have that.

Comment: The http header is in the TCP packet isn't it? How can I know the real UDP destination? The ip destination will always be the router one... no?

Comment: The real destination is the destination IP address in the IP header. Traffic on the same network does not pass through a router. Routers route packets between networks based on the destination IP address. Any packets with the router address as the destination IP address are destined for the router itself.